# Is there any scheduled downtime with Azure DB?

Tags: azure, azure-sql

With a standard SQL Server platform (with no replication or redundancy), some downtime is to be expected for weekly/monthly patching and reboots.

Is this still the case for Azure DBs (elastic pools, serverless, managed instances, etc) ?

Or can I expect them to be operational almost 100% of the time except for unexpected disasters?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft publishes SLA's for all services, the Azure SQL ones can be found [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/support/legal/sla/sql-database/v1_4/).
In summary, the SLA ranges between 99.99% and 99.995% depending on which tier of database you are using.

Comment: Thanks but I'm interested in regular scheduled downtime for weekly patching as might happen for an on-premises SQL Server, not an overall SLA based on incidents.  
Also that page does not list the SLA for Basic or Standard tier

Comment: There is no scheduled maintenance for Azure SQL. The SLA is what you get. Standard and basic is listed in that doc, it is 99.99%